# jQGrid pagination and OData

Tags: jqgrid, odata

My problem lies with jQGrid and an OData data source (.NET WCF)

I am attempting to get jQgrid paging to work correctly, currently I have a basic data load and column sorting functioning.

I did this by overriding the `xmlReader` function to get jQgrid to parse the OData XML

```
xmlReader: {
    root: "feed",
    row: "entry",
    id: "entry>id",
    total: "m:count"
}
```

Then on the request to the server I overrode the `serializeGridData` function to attempt to send the requst in OData format.

```
serializeGridData: function (obj) {
    obj["$inlinecount"] = "allpages";
    obj["$orderby"] = obj.sidx + " " + obj.sord;
    obj["$skip"] = (obj.page - 1) * obj.rows;
    return obj;
}
```

But the problem is the OData response only contains the `m:count` which is the total number of records.  I believe jQGrid needs at least `totalrecords`, `currentpagenum`, and `totalPages` to get the pagination to work correctly.

What am I missing?

A side question is how does Kendo UI Grid accomplish this and is there anything I can learn (or lift) from their code??

Server Side Paging Demo - http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html

Where the demo communicates with an oData source: http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders

Using the same oData format and getting the same response - lacking page number.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like... I've gotten it working for a project I'm on, and I have a gist up that you can peruse...

https://gist.github.com/dealproc/6678280

Comment: glad someone found it useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to use JSON instead of XML to communicate with OData WCF service. If you use ASP.NET 4.X then you will need just include `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"` attribute in settings of the endpoint of WCF service. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16442415/315935) for more details. After that you can just use `datatype: "json"` and  `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }` options of jqGrid. The OData WCF service will returns JSON data.

The example of `serializeGridData`, `jsonReader` and `prmNames` you will [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979809/315935). I think that you can just use the options in your case too.